# CSS break-word and dynamic HTML

Tags: jquery, css

I have that CSS

```
.tooltip-table 
{
    table-layout: fixed !important; 
    width: 250px;
}
.tooltip-table td.leftCol 
{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px !important;
}
.tooltip-table td.rightCol
{    
    width: 150px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

then, I'm creating dynamically bootstrap's tooltip and put that table inside it

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
     var myDiv = $('<div></div>').html('<tr><td class="leftCol">Description</td><td class="rightCol descTD"></td></tr>');

     $('.fc-event-inner', this).attr('data-placement','right')
                               .attr('data-original-title', '<table class="tooltip-table">'+$(myDiv).html()+'</table>')
                               .tooltip({ html: true});

     $('.descTD').html(event.description);

     $('.fc-event-inner', this).tooltip('show');                    
}
```

the problem is, if the multiline HTML `event.description` property is long, that CSS can break the HTML tags and as a result it is being display as a raw text, like

[image]

is it possible to fix it somehow ? I don't have any clue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have edited your code:  please see if it helps.

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
 var myDiv = $('<div><tr><td class="leftCol">Description</td><td class="rightCol descTD"></td></tr></div>');

 $('.fc-event-inner', this).attr('data-placement','right')
                           .attr('data-original-title', '<table class="tooltip-table">'+$(myDiv)+'</table>')
                           .tooltip({ html: true});

 $('.descTD').html(event.description);

 $('.fc-event-inner', this).tooltip('show');
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `word-wrap: break-word`. By definition, it breaks strings arbitrarily (and is seldom adequate). Instead, insert the `<wbr>` tag or otherwise [indicate line breaking opportunity](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) at appropriate places.